# How to configure Grub to show only splash-screen and error messages during boot and shutdown?

Tags: 11.10, boot, shutdown, lxde

I want to know where do I configure grub boot commands and commands called by lxsession-logout.

I wish to make splash screen and **only** error output on both startup and shutdown/reboot.
Startup, as far as I know is somewhere in grub configs but shutdown is called by lxsession-logout and I don't know where it resides.

Comment: This question is missing a good answer yet

Comment: @H_7 I can't test any of these answers since my hard drive is dead, is there a good one here?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing and configuring :`sudo apt-get install startupmanager`.

For changing the grub splash image have a look at [this post.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11369004&postcount=1)

There's also a [plymouth manager](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/11/install-plymouth-manager-and-change.html). On Nvidia & ATI cards you might want to try a [fix script.](http://paolobernardi.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/fix-plymouth-on-ubuntu-after-installing-nvidia-or-ati-proprietary-drivers-for-ubuntu-11-04-natty/)

Lightdm background:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:claudiocn/slm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install simple-lightdm-manager
```

All I've heard of for shutdown is to comment out the following line (i.e., add `#` to the beginning of the line) in `/etc/init/rc.conf`:

```
#console output
```

Comment: While the question isn't totally clear, I think he might be wanting a way to configure Plymouth?

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the boot-up and shutdown process as a whole. They consist of Grub, plymouth and then Lightdm